# Show/get first item, not all of them

Tags: javascript

I have part of a script that gets all labels/tags of a blog post. I want it to only get the very first item, not all of them. I tried various things, but not valid.

Original script:

```
if (json.feed.entry[i].category != null)
      {
        for (var k = 0; k < json.feed.entry[i].category.length; k++)
        {
          postCategory += '<a class="json-post-article-category" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'">'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'</a>';
        }
      }
```

This is my latest attempt:

```
if (json.feed.entry[i].category != null)
      {
        for (postCategory = json.feed.entry[i].category.length = 0)
        {
          postCategory += '<a class="json-post-article-category" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'">'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'</a>';
        }
      }
```

Comment: If you only want the first item, you don't need a loop.

Comment: What does your response look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Just check that array is not empty, and then use `category[0]` instead of `category[k]`.

```
if (json.feed.entry[i].category != null && json.feed.entry[i].category.length > 0)
{
  postCategory += '<a class="json-post-article-category" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+json.feed.entry[i].category[0].term+'">'+json.feed.entry[i].category[0].term+'</a>';
}
```

Comment: What you wrote makes sense to me, but it gives me the error: cannot read property term undefined.

Comment: I didn't notice that there was a second `category[k]` that needed to be changed to `category[0]`.